# Firebase functions: ensure triggered events order

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

We are using firebase functions to send push notifications to our users and we want them to be sent in order.

Is there any way to ensure that the onWrite events are fired/processed in the same order that the elements were inserted? Or they run concurrently and you can't ensure that in any way? In case it's not possible, which solution do you use for those cases?

**Example**: We would like that, if we insert in this order at /foo: item 1, item 2, item 3
the onWrite events are fired ALWAYS in the same order: item1, item2, item3

Many thanks for your help!

**ANSWER**

Well.... we have done some tests and in fact, as we imagined, the events are not triggered in order. Posted messages with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... and as you can see at the following picture they are not processed in order.

[image: Sample output log from Firebase]

Comment: There are no guarantees about the order in which events will be handled by Cloud Functions.

Comment: Also note that [FCM does not guarantee the order of delivery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages).

Comment: I noticed you also posted this on firebase-talk. Let's link them: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/K_X6rnvu5yg

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees) state the following:

> While developing your applications, keep in mind that Cloud Firestore triggers are currently in beta which may result in unexpected behavior.
>
> A few known limitations include:
>
> - It may take up to 10 seconds for a function to be triggered after a change to Cloud Firestore data.
> - **As with all background functions, event ordering is not guaranteed. In addition, a single event may result in multiple Cloud Functions invocations, so for the highest quality ensure your functions are written to be idempotent.**

In other words, Firestore triggers alone are not enough to accomplish the task.

One option would be to instead maintain a timestamp on your documents. Then when the relevant trigger occurs, you can sort all the documents that require a push notification to be sent.